# How to navigate into different component from nested route in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React-Router and on my navbar i would navigate from nested route into different component.

Scenario:

On my navbar i have links to components:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar onSaveLoginState={saveLoginState} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/movies" component={Films} />
          <Route exact path="/movies/:id" component={FilmsDetailed} />
          <Route exact path="/routing" component={RoutingExample} />
          <Route exact path="/routing/:arrow" component={Child} />
          <Route exact path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Then i enter 'routing/something' and when i want to navigate from navbar into different component on my url only end addres is changing like so: routing/profile, routing/movies but page is still the same. My question is how to navigate correctly from that place into different componenets?

```
const RoutingExample = () => {
  let { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div className="container border border-primary">
      <ul>
        <li>
          {`useParams ->`}
          <Link to={`${url}/arrow`}>
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">Click</button>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RoutingExample;
```

On my navbar:

```
<nav className={styles.nav}>
  <h1 className={styles.nav__logo}>MOVIES</h1>
  <ul className={`${styles.list} ${isOpen ? styles["list--active"] : ""}`}>
    {navigationLinks.map((link, index) => {
      return (
        <li className={styles["list--item"]} key={index}>
          <Link to={link.url}>{link.title}</Link>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onLogin}>
    Login
  </button>
  <span>LoggedIn: {login.toString()}</span>
  <div className={styles["cart-container"]}>
    <RiShoppingCartLine
      size="2.8rem"
      className={styles["cart-container__icon"]}
    />
    <span className={styles["cart-container__inner"]}>171</span>
  </div>
  <button className={styles.hamburger} onClick={onToggleOpenMenu}>
    {isOpen ? <FaTimes /> : <GiHamburgerMenu />}
  </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <h1 className={styles.nav__logo}>MOVIES</h1>
  <ul className={`${styles.list} ${isOpen ? styles["list--active"] : ""}`}>
<li className={styles["list--item"]} key={1}>
    <Link to="/movies">Movies</Link> /*And all links like that*/
</li>
  </ul>
  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onLogin}>
    Login
  </button>
  <span>LoggedIn: {login.toString()}</span>
  <div className={styles["cart-container"]}>
    <RiShoppingCartLine
      size="2.8rem"
      className={styles["cart-container__icon"]}
    />
    <span className={styles["cart-container__inner"]}>171</span>
  </div>
  <button className={styles.hamburger} onClick={onToggleOpenMenu}>
    {isOpen ? <FaTimes /> : <GiHamburgerMenu />}
  </button>
</nav>
```

You need to put the path value you wrote in route into "to" in your Link
for example
`<Route path="/movies" component={Films} />`
to access it use
 `<Link to="/movies"> Movies <Link/>`

Comment: Did you read my question? I'm asking for navigation from navbar..

Comment: What is the navigationLinks value.

Comment: And I 'm so sorry that I didn't understand the question well